# Blender Shortcut on Switching tab

Tags: shortcut

Im wondering is there a shortcut on blender to switch tab like for example im on "Layout" tab and i would like to switch to "Uv editing" tab i wonder is there a shortcut for that ? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all let's find the right term. You can do that by hovering the mouse over it. They are called "Workspaces". Then you know what to search for in the keymap that you can find in the Preferences:

[image]

Apparently you can cycle through workspaces with <kbd>PgUp</kbd>, <kbd>PgDown</kbd> keys.

Comment: Thank you very much i able to scroll over the workspace easily.